# Obtain the value of the class when click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to activate a function every time the user clicks on a button that has a certain class. I'm trying to get the value of the button clicked, and so far, failing.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    $('.button').click(function(item) {
        console.log(item.value);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" value="7">7</button>
```

The expected result would be "7", since that is the value of the button. Currently, I'm getting undefined.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `item.target.value` or `this.value` to reach the element instead of the event object.

Comment: Use `console.log(item)` to see what you actually have: an event.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. I was looking through everything that the event has, but I simply didn't see the value.

Comment: @IvanPenev if my solution worked for you, could you mark my solution as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basic one...

Pure jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function(item) {
    console.clear();
    console.log( $(this).text(), ' = ', $(this).val() );
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" value="7">bt 7</button>
<button class="button" value="8">bt 8</button>
```

Pure JS:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(bt=>{
    bt.onclick=e=>{
      console.clear()
      console.log(e.target.textContent,' = ', e.target.value) 
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="button" value="7"> bt 7 </button>

<button class="button" value="8"> bt 8 </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your want to stick with using just JQuery, Use `$(this).val()` That should get you the value of the button.

change your JS to this:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('.button').click(function(item) {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Try out this Jsfiddle as well to see if this is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/9zjLfso8/

Also if you're going to use jQuery, I would recommend that you use `$(document).ready` instead of `window.onload`. Here's a link to see the difference between the two: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('.button').click(function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.textContent);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with vanilla JavaScript:

```
   <button class="button" 
   onclick="myFunc(7)">7</button>
```

The script:

```
   function myFunc(value){
       console.log(value)
   }
```

Comment: With that small script? How?

Comment: Ah i see, i forgot the "function" at the end